# Printing (or unescaping JSON) with nodejs and jade

Tags: pug

I've been digging through Jade documentation and google searches but nothing words. I'm attempting to print a JSON string with a view but no matter how I try to print the variable, the double quotes are always converted to `&quot;`

Update: I'm using Jade 0.26.0.

My test json:

```
{test:"value"}
```

My template code:

```
!{JSON.stringify(json)}
```

Raw output in the web browser:

```
{&quot;test&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}
```

Answer (score 35):

Maybe upgrade to more recent version of Jade?

I'm using version 0.25.0 and..

This is escaped

```
=JSON.stringify(item)
```

These are unescaped

```
!{JSON.stringify(item)}
!=JSON.stringify(item)
```

Comment: Neither of those are working for me. I'm using Jade 0.26 and have edited my post simplifying the test.

Comment: I just tried it and

    `script(type='text/javascript')
        !{JSON.stringify(item)}`

works perfectly fine for me. (The code is in two rows and indended actually)

Comment: Just tried this with the latest version of express and it does not show the raw json but the literal script(type='text/javascript') !{JSON.stringify(item)}.

Comment: If you dump the object out into the browser console it's a bit easier to navigate: `script console.log(!{JSON.stringify(item)});`.

Comment: I'm using `pug` version: 2.0.0-beta6 and `!{JSON.stringify(obj)}` throws an error. However `!=JSON.stringify(obj)` works.