# node.js render method

Tags: node.js, express, pug

My question is very simple. I am using the node.js with express and jade view engine.
When I render some file and send in field of object HTML tags, in the file I get a funny laughableness. For example:
**app.js**

```
res.render('not_found', { 
 field: "<a href='/'>main page</a>"
});
```

**in file not_found.jade**

```
&lt;a href='/'&gt;main page&lt;/a&gt;
```

---

And my question: how can I send a html code in in the value of an object field?

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: show us the code where you configure your express app!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing (or unescaping JSON) with nodejs and jade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748222/printing-or-unescaping-json-with-nodejs-and-jade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to use the proper code in your template so that it isn't escaped, as the jade documentation explains in the [Tag Text](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a6-3) section.

Interpolation with `#{}` will be escaped, as you saw.  If you need *unescaped* interpolation, you need to use `!{}` to tell jade not to mangle up your data.

If you haven't seen [Jade Syntax Documentation by Example - escaping](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#escaping), it gives a few examples of this.  The rest of the page is ***very*** useful as you can edit/test your ideas.

And to answer your question, you'd need to change your jade template from `#{field}` to `!{field}`.